# How to use Apple earbuds with PC laptop?

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones, pc

I'd like to be able use my wired iPhone earbuds with my PC laptop. My laptop has the standard 3.5 mm audio jack.

So from what I can tell, I need a female lighting to a male 3.5mm adapter.  So the first problem is that I can't find something like that at all.

The closest thing I found is this monstrosity below.  I would plug in my earbuds into the right most slot.  Then buy a male to male 3.5mm adapter and plug it in to the adapter on one end and my laptop on the other.  And hope that it works.

So my questions:

1. Is there a better way?
2. Would the setup I describe even work, given that I am only using the right side of the device?

[image]

P.S.  Found a [product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07R6MKJZH) that meets my requirement.

Comment: I don't think this works at all: the left male is meant to plug it into an iPhone, the middle female is for an ear phone (= audio out) and the right female is meant for male-male lightning as charging cable plugged into a Mac on the other side.

Comment: The lightning port doesn’t have audio pins; instead the audio adapter has a small DAC (digital audio converter chip) to convert the signals.   It’s one way.  Given that Earbuds are “throwaway” it’s highly unlikely you’ll find adapters for them